# Calculate $0,2\overline{91}$ using geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, decimal-expansion

I need to calculate $0,2\overline{91}$ using geometric series.

Not sure if these steps are correct:

$$0,2\overline{91} = \frac{2}{10} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{91}{(1000)^n}$$

so:
$$0,2\overline{91} = \frac{2}{10} + 91 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1000)^n} $$
$$0,2\overline{91} = \frac{2}{10} + 91 \bigg(\frac{1}{1- \frac{1}{1000}} -1\bigg) $$
$$0,2\overline{91} = \frac{2}{10} + 91 \bigg(\frac{1000}{999} - 1\bigg) $$
$$0,2\overline{91} = \frac{2}{10} + 91 \bigg(\frac{1000 - 999}{999}\bigg) $$
$$0,2\overline{91} = \frac{2}{10} + \frac{91}{999} $$

is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct. That $1000$ should be $100$. I think that it's better to see it this way: if your number is $x$, then\begin{align}10x&=2,\overline{91}\\&=2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{91}{100^n}\\&=2+\frac{91}{99}\end{align}and therefore$$x=\frac15+\frac{91}{990}.$$

Comment: Thanks @josè just one question, at the end, the second fraction should be $\frac{91}{990}$ am I right?

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not correct. *Another point of view* is to write
$$
x=0.0\overline{91}
$$ then, by periodicity,
$$
1000x=91+10x,\qquad 990x=91, 
$$that is
$$
0.0\overline{91}=\frac{91}{990}
$$and

> $$
> 0.\color{red}{2}\overline{91}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{5}}+\frac{91}{990}=\frac{289}{990}.
> $$